# How to disable manual input in a Telerik RadDatePicker

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, raddatepicker

I am using a Telerik `RadDatePicker`, and I want to disable input by the user, but they should be able to select from the calender.

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker Culture="{Binding GetLanguage}" x:Name="startDate" 
                       Margin="0,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" TabIndex="2"
                       MinWidth="120" Width="120" Height="Auto" MaxHeight="25"
                       KeyDown="filterDate_KeyDown" >
</telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

I have used `KeyDown` but it did not help.

Comment: you can disable it with jquery...

Comment: can u please explain with description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PreviewKeyDown event exists exactly for this sort of thing.

```
private void spacebarHandler_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
if (e.Key == Key.Space)
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy solution to this problem.

Adding the property `EnableTyping="false"` prevents the user from typing.

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker runat="server" ID="rdpPreviousDay" EnableTyping="false"></telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the `KeyDown` event:

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker KeyDown="StartDate_OnKeyDown" />
```

And then "handle" all keys, which effectively disables the user from typing anything:

```
private void StartDate_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Interestingly, there's an `IsReadOnly` property on the `RadDatePicker`, which disables the `DatePickerTextBox` and still allows the user to *view* the calendar, but unfortunately it also prevents the user from actually making a selection in the calendar. It makes it *look* like you can select a date, but then it doesn't actually set the `SelectedDate` property.

Comment: Thank you, also is there any way so that user cannot delete it present date using backspace

Answer (score 0):

Set the IsHitTestVisible=False, problem solved.

```
    <telerik:RadDatePicker                          
    SelectedDate="{Binding ValidFrom,Mode=TwoWay}" >
                <telerik:RadDatePicker.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox">
                        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />                          
                    </Style>
                </telerik:RadDatePicker.Resources>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a property `DateInput-ReadOnly`.  Set it to `true` and you should be good to go.